# Как распаковать проект скачанный из Github?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, github, npm

Скачал проект из гитхаба. при открытии index.html ничего не работает.
В инструкции пишется так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как распаковать проект? я не знаю что такое npm

вот директория:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужна пака node_modules. Нужно установить nodeJs и в папке с проектом прописать в терминале npm i или npm install, а потом запустить проект через команду npm run

Comment: Начать нужно с [установки Node.js](https://nodejs.org/uk/) после установки вы можете в консоли (терминале) вводить указанные команды

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, то, что вы скачали с github, называется `project`.

Создайте папку `c:\project` и положите туда все эти файлы из zip-архива.

Зайдите на сайт https://nodejs.org/, скачайте версию для Windows, установите, перезагрузитесь.

Теперь у вас есть npm.

Теперь нажмите "Пуск", найдите "Командная строка". Введите

```
cd c:\project
npm install
npm run build
npm run watch
```

Тогда, может быть, запустится.